# What is required to allow SignalR to integrate with a third party WebSockets server?

Tags: websocket, signalr, owin, katana, websocket4net

### 2 Part question

1. Am I implementing this client correctly?
2. If I were to implement my own WebSockets server, what are my requirements for allowing SignalR's transport negotiation process to recognize WebSockets and be able to use it for its communications?

Note that my technology constraints currently involve

- Windows 7,
- Framework 4.5,
- Owin Self-Hosted(console) SignalR server,
- Owin self-hosted(console) .NET Client,
- Web Client (Javascript)

---

### Part 1: Attempt to implement Katana sample with System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket Client

So I'm in the process of building out a self-hosted SignalR process and I noticed in my fiddler traffic that my connection is using LongPolling when I would prefer it to use WebSockets, so I went about the process of researching what would be required to make WebSockets available.

Some quick research resulted in mixed information: 
Some sources indicated that WebSockets was only available on Windows 8 and IIS 8 and that the WebSockets implementation was integrated at the OS level.

Some sources indicated that that limitation was only for parties wanting to use HTTP.sys and that a self-hosted solution could utilize WebSockets:
[Katana Sample WebSocket Server](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Katana/WebSocketSample/WebSocketServer/Startup.cs)
[Katana Sample WebSocket Client](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Katana/WebSocketSample/SampleClient/Program.cs)

so I went about implementing the Katana sample -I have a SignalR server that I'm wanting to expose via WebSockets, a .NET Client, and a Web Client- into my SignalR server and when I attempt to execute the following code in my .NET Client (snipping the portions of the client code that aren't currently relevant):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗");
            Console.WriteLine("╠»»»-                     Starting Service.Host-                   «««╣");

            Console.WriteLine("║-- Connecting to Client Messaging Hub-- ");
            Console.WriteLine("║.....Attempting to upgrade to WebSockets ");

            //UseDefaultConnectionParameters();
            Connect("ws://localhost:8080");

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("║-->Connection Established [{0}]", @"ws://localhost:8080"));
            Console.WriteLine("╠»»»                   Service.Host now  started                   «««╣");
            Console.WriteLine("╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        private static async Task Connect(string uri)
        {
            ClientWebSocket websocket = null;
            try
            {
                websocket = new ClientWebSocket();//<= Throws exception
                await websocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
                await Task.WhenAll(Receive(websocket), Send(websocket));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (websocket != null)
                    websocket.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine();

                lock(master)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }


        }
```

the line inside my Connect() function

```
ClientWebSocket websocket = new System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket();
```

throws

```
Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The WebSocket protocol is not s
upported on this platform.
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket..ctor().
```

(My CLR Client library targets .NET Framework 4.5)

Is this running into a hard limit that you cannot -in fact- create a WebSocket Client from the System.Net.WebSockets namespace without Windows 8?

### Part 2: Investigating implications of Third-Party WebSocket Server/Client

Assuming that the code from Part 1 is a dead end, I imagine my next viable option is to implement a third party Web Sockets server (such as [SuperWebSocket](https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperWebSocket)) with an appropriate Client (such as  [SignalR.Client.WebSocket4Net](https://github.com/esskar/SignalR.Client.WebSocket4Net)) and expose the socket server for SignalR to consume.  I'm hoping the answer will be "nothing. It will just work" but once I stand SuperWebSocket up and extend my CLR Client to implement SignalR.Client.WebSocket4Net, what will be required to have SignalR communications negotiate the upgrade request and start transporting over ws:// ?

---

Can anyone provide any guidance down either of these two paths?   I foresee a lot of wasted time if I choose the wrong route.

Answer (score 0):

### Part 1

The new version of http.sys, shipped into Windows 8 and 2012, is the piece responsible of turning a regular HTTP request into a persistent, binary, bidirectional TCP connection that is a WebSocket. That is what allows IIS to switch protocols when a websocket connection is made.

Why ClientWebSockets does not work on Windows 7? Well, it does not make sense at all, but probably there are some shared functionality between server and client and that is the reason why it is blocked in "old" operating systems with the `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

### Part 2

You would probably need to implement your own [ITransport](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Transports/ITransport.cs) to create your own [WebSocketTransport](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Transports/WebSocketTransport.cs), and register it in the [TransportManager](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Transports/TransportManager.cs). This is pure speculation, I have never tried to do something like that :) Just, be wary of the little documentation or experiences you can find about this...

But here comes the problem, if your client switches to another transport, it will fail! Because since the operating system cannot listen in the same port for long polling and websockets, a regular HTTP request to the WebSocket component will have no effect what so ever. That is the trick that http.sys does in its new version, listen for HTTP regular requests, and still can turn one of them on a websocket if required.

### My 0.02

Why SignalR? It is a polyfill that will not be needed very soon. WebSockets is a standard, broadly supported technology and easy to polyfill in old browsers with [websocket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js). SignalR is [just good for applications that broadcast general data](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr) (check the limitations section). I wrote and maintain a [WebSocket library named WebSocketListener](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/), you may want to give it a try :) (it does not have a client though). I recommend you to test several libraries for performance and scalability before choosing one ;)